# dealing with s-expressions in javascript without paredit

Tags: yank, kill-text

I was using paredit for other languages apart from lisp and it was great for being able to delete and yank whole functions etc. but it was also quite buggy with `web-mode` and `js2-mode`.

Fir example, I could hit ctrl + K at the first line of the code below:

```
const  = (x) => {
  // function body
};
```

and it would cut the entire function. This worked with html in web-mode etc.

Is there anyway I can replicate this behaviour without paredit or how do more seasoned emacs users go about copying whole expressions like this or working with them in non-lisp languages?

Comment: Have you tried `kill-sexp`, which is bound to `C-M-k`? It kills the next sexp. There is also `backward-kill-sexp`, bound to `C-M-<backspace>`, which kills the previous sexp.

Comment: I guess that doesn't work, because all of that text is not one sexp. So try `C-M-h` to select it all, then `C-w` to kill it. (Presumably it is a defun.) That doesn't seem to include the `;` at the end, however.

Comment: `C-M-` means press and hold Control plus Alt keys (`C-` is Control, `M-` is Meta, which is usually Alt). (However, for `C-M-<backspace>` you might need to use `ESC C-<backspace>`. You can use `ESC` as a prefix key instead of `Alt` as a modifier key.)

Comment: What about using paragraphs for it? You can mark an entire paragraph with `M-h` and then kill it or do something else with it.